# ¿En que contexto o cuando se usa un estilo (style) global (app.xaml), local (windows resource) etc?

Tags: c#, xaml, buenas-prácticas

hace poco que estoy programando en c# y debido a que hay multiples formas de definir los estilos (style) de los componentes en c# y que estos aunque parecidos no son iguales a los de CSS (con el que si he trabajado más), no tengo del todo claro cuando debería definir un estilo como global, local, en el propio componente etc.

Para los controles tenemos multiples formas de definir su apariencia:

- Estilo global (Style de app.xaml)
- Estilo local (Style en windows resource de la propia ventana xaml)
- Estilo en el propio componente (Definir el Style en el propio elemento, esto debido a que conozco CSS me parece la peor idea pero me gustaría saber las opiniones o si es bueno usarlo en ciertos contextos)
- Plantillas o controles personalizados (Templates y Custom controller)

He investigado un poco y he encontrado algo de información, pero no mucha, basicamente que no se debe en el estilo global referenciar a tipos generales como puede ser textblock porque esto puede tener consecuencias inesperadas, es decir no usar por ejemplo

Style TargetType: textblock

Style based on x:type textblock

y en lugar de esto, usar x:key.

Aparte de eso algo de información sobre las plantillas donde recomienda usarlas para cosas más situaciones en las que permites al usuario modificar el aspecto y los controles de usuario, para cuando el estilo ya esta definido y no va a ser modificado por el usuario.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841324/templated-control-vs-custom-control-in-uwp-no-clear-answer-found-online

Pero no he entendido del todo a que se refiere, si es que el template sería por ejemplo una ventana que el usuario pudiera definir su apariencia en configuración por ejemplo o a que exactamente.

El motivó de estas dudas, aparte de para aprender un poco más sobre C# es porque estoy haciendo un proyecto en C#, y a la hora de definir las ventanas, sus componentes etc, pues tengo muchas dudas de si primero se define en app.xaml los estilos comunes de la aplicación y luego en windows resource modificamos esos estilos o creamos los especificos de cada ventana, o si en el app.xaml solo debería haber elementos comunes y todo lo demás se crean en windows resource sin based on si no entero de 0, o como debería hacerlo.

Comment: Esta pregunta es altamente basada en opiniones :(... no habria forma de que hubiera una respuesta correcta. Salvo que haya un manual de estilo de MS, y tomaras eso como fuente.. Pero en general, en cada lugar se impone la forma que sea mas comoda...

Comment: Hola, comprendo que en la pregunta hay una carga de opinión, el problema es que la verdad no se me ocurre como indicar el titulo, de manera de dejar claro que simplemente quiero saber si más o menos hay una forma de trabajo definida, o como se suelo hacer para no hacer una mezcla absurda de estilos sin ton ni son que al final me perjudiquen más que me ayuden